# Apple Pay проблема с сертификатами

Tags: php, curl

Когда на стороне сервера делаю запрос, для старта сессии(Apple session), по url который получаю с клиентской части, появляется ошибка curl "**peer does not recognize and trust the ca that issued your certificate**". Сертификат merchant identifier был в расширении .p12. Я конвертировал его в два .pem-файла(ключ и сертификат). Что может быть причиной этой ошибки?

````
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, public_path('apple_pay/crt/Apple.cer.pem'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,  public_path('apple_pay/crt/Apple.key.pem'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $pass);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); ```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: английским по белому же написано что удаленный хост не доверяет вашему сертификату (подозреваю что он самоподписанный)